# How does best-first search suffer from plateau and local maxima?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, artificial-intelligence, state-space

I understand that this particular algorithm suffers from these issues, however when I am researching the actual meanings of each one I can not grasp the concept. Can someone please explain how these are problems and whether 'Ridges and Alleys' affects it to.

Here is a related question which you may also find useful:
[What are the problems associated to Best First Search in Artificial intelligence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950307/what-are-the-problems-associated-to-best-first-search-in-artificial-intelligence)

Comment: Read the article on Hill Climbing on Wikipedia. It has some good explanation of the concepts along with some graphics. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) The steepest ascent hill climbing variant is very similar to best-first search.

Comment: Just saw your [other question on the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950307/what-are-the-problems-associated-to-best-first-search-in-artificial-intelligence). It would have been nice to have a link to it in this question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Wikipedia was the source I was origonally looking at, I have a vague understanding now but it's not clear. Are there any other issues surrounding best first search algorithm aside from the ones mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider yourself traversing a landscape, trying to get to the highest peak. With BFS, your only rule is to go up. What happens if you get to the top of a small hill? Where do you go if you reach level ground?